# BigInteger negative value

Tags: java, biginteger

I have a biginteger number, say

```
BigInteger a=Biginteger.valueOf(50);
```

Besides the following

```
BigInteger a=(BigInteger.ZERO).subtract(BigInteger.valueOf(50));
```

is there another way to get the negative value of my number? Can't seem to find a method.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're looking for [`BigInteger`'s `negate()` method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html#negate()).